# Sorting Grid by column

Tags: c#

I want to sort a Gridview in a MultiView which also uses an UpdataPanel. When i run the program and click on the GridView columns its not sorting but shows the following error when i inspect the page:

> MsAjaxJs?v=c42ygB2U07n37m_Sfa8ZbLGVu4Rr2gsBo7MvUEnJeZ81:1 Uncaught
>   Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object.
>       at Function.Error.create (MsAjaxJs?v=c42ygB2U07n37m_Sfa8ZbLGVu4Rr2gsBo7MvUEnJeZ81:1)
>       at Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._createPageRequestManagerServerError
>   (MsAjaxJs?v=c42ygB2U07n37m_Sfa8ZbLGVu4Rr2gsBo7MvUEnJeZ81:1)

My Source Code:

**GridView Code:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdProcessed" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
                       ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Both" EnableViewState="false"
                        ShowFooter="True" width="100%" AllowPaging="True" AutoResize="false"  AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="GridProcessed_Sorting"  OnRowDataBound="ProcessedGrid_RowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewProcessed_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="20" PagerStyle-Font-Size="Large"  > 
                        <PagerStyle CssClass="gvPagerCss"/>
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />

                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="PanicID" HeaderText="PanicID"  InsertVisible="False" Visible="False" ReadOnly="True" >
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />

                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Reference" HeaderText="Reference"   ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="Reference" >
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />

                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="IDNumber" HeaderText="ID number"  ReadOnly="true"  SortExpression="IDNumber" >
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"  />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First name"  SortExpression="FirstName">
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />

                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Surname" HeaderText="Last name"  SortExpression="Surname">
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="EmailAddress" HeaderText="Email address"   SortExpression="EmailAddress">
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="CellNumber" HeaderText="Cell number"   SortExpression="CellNumber">
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"  />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="PanicRequestDate" HeaderText="Date panic requested"  SortExpression="PanicRequestDate" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy/hh:mm}">
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"  />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProcessedBy" HeaderText="Processed by"  SortExpression="ProcessedBy">
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"  />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateProcessed" HeaderText="Date panic processed"  SortExpression="DateProcessed" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy/hh:mm}">
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"  />
                            </asp:BoundField>
```

CS File:

```
public WebGrid Grid { get { return gRd; } }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["user"] == null)
    Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login");

    SetLinkLabels();
}


protected void GridProcessed_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{


    DataSet dsSortTable = grdProcessed.DataSource as DataSet;
    DataTable dtSortTable = dsSortTable.Tables[0];
    DataView dvSortedView = new DataView(dtSortTable);

    if ((ViewState["sorting"]).ToString() =="DESC" | ViewState["sorting"] == null)
    {
        dvSortedView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " ASC";
        ViewState["sorting"] = "ASC";
    }
    else if(ViewState["sorting"].ToString()=="ASC")
    {
        dvSortedView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " DESC";
        ViewState["sorting"] = " DSC";
    }

    grdProcessed.DataSource = dvSortedView;
    grdProcessed.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: I usually sort the DataTable : dtSortTable = dtSortTable.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Field<string>("user")).CopyToDataTable();

Comment: its not working this side

Comment: Does dtSortTable contain any rows?  Are you getting any exceptions?  Does the datatable contain the column "user"?  Is the user column a string?

Comment: DataTable dtSort = dtSortTable.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Field<string>("FirstName")).CopyToDataTable();

Comment: So now does the code work with FirstName?

Comment: This is what i did but nothing is working no exceptions. I dont have the column "user".So i tried using column "FirstName": DataTable dtSort = dtSortTable.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Field<string>("FirstName")).CopyToDataTable();

Comment: Its not working .If i click the column header "FirstName"  nothing happens

Comment: No its not  working.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to verify your table(s) have rows.  I usually put a break point after the table(s) are filled.   The hover over the bariable for the dataset and click the down arrow and then select the Data Visualizer to see the data.  If you have a DataSet there is a pull-down box so you can look at all the tables.

Comment: I did put a break-point but its saying:"The break-point will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document".

Comment: The find out why you aren't getting to the break point.

Comment: I managed to sort  the break point issue ,but dtSortTable is null.

Comment: Are you still using user instead of FirstName? if (Session["user"] == null)